# How to use JCMSegmentPageController with Storyboards?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, relationship

I recently found [JCMSegmentPageController](https://github.com/jcmendez/JCMSegmentPageController), which offers the functionality of a UITabBarController using a segmented control on the top instead of a tabbar on the bottom.

I intended using it in an upcoming project, however found it impossible to wire it up in a storyboard.

I've thought about different possibilities to solve the problem, because one cannot currently create relationship-segues:

- using a wrapper-object that subclasses UITabBarController to "steal" the view-controllers-relationship
- using an IBOutletCollection and placeholder-objects
- using a custom segue, which does not switch between the controllers but instead transforms the view to fit into the "parent" and provide it for embedding

However, all of them seem more or less hackish to me and I would like to ask for a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick

The way I use it along with storyboards is shown below:

[image: Using JCMSegmentPageController in storyboard]

I create the contained view controllers, and don't set a segue relationship.  On the image below, the leftmost VC is a JCMSegmentPageController subclass.  The other two at the right are the contained VCs.

Then I assign a unique id for each of the contained VCs, in this case, EvstEveryJourneyTableView and EvstFollowingJourneyTableView.

[image: Setting the identifier for the ViewController]

Finally, I instantiate them with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, as shown below:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  EvstEverybodyJourneyTableViewController *jvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EvstEveryJourneyTableView"];
    EvstEverybodyJourneyTableViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EvstFollowingJourneyTableView"];
  self.delegate = self;
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:jvc, dvc, nil];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, Juan. so it looks like doing it programmatically is indeed the easiest way.